# Extracting 4 lines from a file on matching a pattern in 1st line

Tags: unix, awk, grep

Problem :

To extract data of 4 lines (including line of pattern match) from a file when a pattern matches.

Example

```html
<div class="class1">
<img class="class2" src="somelink" alt="xyz">
<div class="class3" title="some data to be extracted">
<div class="class4" style="width: 72%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
<img class="class2" src="somelink2" alt="xyz2">
<div class="class3" title="some data to be extracted 2">
<div class="class4" style="width: 72%;"></div>
</div>
```

Matching pattern -> class1

Data needs to be extracted :

```html
    <div class="class1">
    <img class="class2" src="somelink" alt="xyz">
    <div class="class3" title="some data to be extracted">
    <div class="rating-wrap" style="width: 72%;"></div>
    </div>
```

Solutions i was trying :

```
grep class1 xyz.html
```

But this will get only single line.

Comment: try `grep -A4 -m1 class1 xyz.html` , and this question should be a duplicate.

Comment: not working. Just tried.

Comment: works for me ! I've edited the comment, try now.

Comment: I tried this grep -A4 class1 xyz.html it worked for me. I don't know what does -m1 do.

Comment: stop after 1st match

Comment: That might be causing issue. removing -m1 is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -A4 class1 xyz.html
```

This will fetch the same

```
<div class="class1">
<img class="class2" src="somelink" alt="xyz">
<div class="class3" title="some data to be extracted">
<div class="rating-wrap" style="width: 72%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too bad you didn't create 2 different blocks in your input so you could see the results of the matching of "class1" succeeding for one but not the other. Anyway, you really want this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n</div>\n"} /class1/' file
<div class="class1">
<img class="class2" src="somelink" alt="xyz">
<div class="class3" title="some data to be extracted">
<div class="class4" style="width: 72%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
<img class="class2" src="somelink2" alt="xyz2">
<div class="class3" title="some data to be extracted 2">
<div class="class4" style="width: 72%;"></div>
</div>
```

because it will print the block that the matching string appears in regardless of where in the block it matches, e.g.:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n</div>\n"} /extracted 2/' file
<div class="class1">
<img class="class2" src="somelink2" alt="xyz2">
<div class="class3" title="some data to be extracted 2">
<div class="class4" style="width: 72%;"></div>
</div>
```

and it can be easily tweaked to only look for a match in a specific field so, for example, a search for class1 only looks at the class= field and not the title= field or anywhere else on the line.

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS.